# Cannot download DOC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, ms-word

How do i call on `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing,
                                                                                    ref missing, ref missing);` when i want to put it in my filestream?

```
        //DOC download
    private void DownloadDoc()
    {
        object fileName = LabelFirstNameFromDb.Text + "_" + LabelLastNameFromDb.Text + "_" +
              DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "." + DropDownListDownload.SelectedItem.Text;

        var db = new KnowItCvdbEntities();

        SPWeb theSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
        SPUser theUser = theSite.CurrentUser;
        string strUserName = theUser.LoginName;

        var theEmpl = (from p in db.EMPLOYEES
                       where p.username == strUserName
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();

        if (theEmpl != null)
        {
            object missing = Missing.Value;
            object start1 = 0;

            var wordApp = new ApplicationClass();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing,
                                                                                ref missing, ref missing);

            Range rng = myDoc.Range(ref start1, ref missing);

            try
            {
                object fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + fileName,
                                                              FileMode.Create);

                myDoc.SaveAs(ref fileStream, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                wordApp.Visible = true;

                const char newLine = (char)11;

                //CERTIFICATES
                string certificate = string.Empty;
                var lbCertificate = new Label();
                foreach (var vCert in BulletedListCertificates.Items)
                {
                    certificate += "  - " + vCert + newLine;
                }

                lbCertificate.Text = newLine + LabelCertificates.Text + newLine + certificate;
                rng.InsertAfter(lbCertificate.Text);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                myDoc.Save();

                if (RadioButtonListLanguage.SelectedItem.Text == "Swedish")
                {
                    RepeaterAssignments.Controls.Clear();
                    SetCustomizedCvAssignmentsSkillSwe();
                }
                else if (RadioButtonListLanguage.SelectedItem.Text == "English")
                {
                    RepeaterAssignments.Controls.Clear();
                    SetCustomizedCvAssignmentsSkillEng();
                }
            }

            Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + fileName);
            Response.End(); 
        }
    }
```